# How to repeat last mapping/action?

Tags: repeated-commands

I know that I can repeat last change with `.`, last command with `@:` and last motion with repmo plugin. What about other actions such as switching to the previous/next tab (`gT`/`gt`)? Is there a command for that?

Comment: You can always make quick [macros](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/repeat.txt.html#recording) to repeat things that don't have their own built-in repeat functions.

Comment: It's not *exactly* the same question, but the answers here are relevant, in that they confirm that not *everything* you do in Vim is easily repeatable: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3978/can-i-repeat-the-last-ui-command?rq=1

Comment: @Rich ah, indeed my question is almost a duplicate of that one. Very helpful, thanks!